# CUDA memory bank conflict?

Tags: cuda, gpu, gpu-shared-memory

I have written a simple code that only launches one block and one thread inside the block. The kernel creates one 48 KB `__shared__` memory array, filling the entire shared memory of the streaming multiprocessor. The code sets and unsets individual bits in the shared memory. I have noticed that with the first 32 bits, the code works fine. However, as I start flipping remaining bits, nothing happens and the bits stay unchanged.

Any ideas what is going on? I am new to CUDA programming. Is there any reason to believe that this has something to do with memory bank conflicts?

Comment: You generally can't use all available shared memory since a small amount is used for kernel function parameters etc.

Comment: Is there a way to determine how much I can use? Even if I could not use the entire shared memory, I should still be able to access the 2nd 32 bit word, like I am doing in my code?

Comment: Without seeing the actual code it's hard to say where you might be going wrong.

Comment: The problem was not memory access. I was declaring wrong offsets for bit shifts. It's resolved now. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Paul R, shared memory is only used for function parameters on sm_1x GPUs.  sm_20 and later GPUs use constant memory for passing function parameters.

Comment: Using --ptxas-options=-v on the compiler you get the amount of used registers, shared memory and local memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, NO, this has nothing to do with shared memory bank conflicts.  Bank conflicts only affect performance, not correctness. Thus you would get the same result with or without bank conflicts.

You should add error checking to your host code and check the result returned from all cuda API functions.  I suspect you are getting an error somewhere.  In general you should post code with your questions if you want a more accurate answer.